# Finding the True Mean: How to solve this?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

This is the last question I have to ask for a project at my university, I have until the 20th of August to answer this, but I have been staring at it all week and have found no clues that I can understand in the book provided to me by the university. I'm bordering on desperate now.

> Can packaging of a healthy food product influence child´s desire to consume the product? This was the question of interest in an article published in the Journal of Consumer Behaviour (Vol. 10, 2011). A fictitious brand of a healthy food product – sliced apples- was packaged to appeal to children (a smiling cartoon apple was on the front of the package). The researchers showed the packaging to a sample of 408 school children and asked each whether he or she was willing to eat the product. Willingness to eat was measured on a 5-point scale, with 1 = “not willing at all” and 5 = “very willing”. The data are summarized as follows: x-bar = 3.69, s = 2.44. Suppose the researchers knew that the mean willingness to eat an actual brand of sliced apples (which is not packaged for children) is µ = 3.
>
> a) Conduct a test to determine whether the true mean willingness to eat the brand of sliced apples packaged for children exceeded 3. Use α = 0.05 to make your conclusion. (2.5 points)
>
> b) The data (willingness to eat values) are not normally distributed. How does this impact (if at all) the validity of your conclusion in part a)? (0.5 points)

So basically I need the answer to this. I have tried everything I can remember and I find nothing.

I'm certain it has something to do with a hypothesis test for the true mean, but I lack the knowledge on how to properly solve it, or if it is the Z-value or the T-value or something else they are asking me to provide.

I tried using this formula:     Z=(3.69-3)/(2.44/√408)=5.71. And then I realised that I didn't even use the α =0.05 that part A demands I use.

Comment: MC Pluto, you seem to have added more context, but I edited your question and somehow now it does not appear. Could you check?

Comment: I'll add it again, thanks for the help btw

Comment: If you use a more descriptive title, I suspect you would get better and improved feedback on your question.

Comment: Does the new title help?

Comment: Hint for b): Consider the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the test this calculation has to yield a Z-score which is "sufficiently large," for which $Z>Z_{1-.05}=Z_{.95}\approx 1.55$. What that means is if we were to suppose, contrary to what we believe, that the true mean of a child's willingness to eat sliced apples from the smiling apple package was only $3$ (the null hypothesis) then the probability of a Z-score larger than 1.55 is only $5$%. The fact that our Z-score was larger than $1.55$ is considered sufficient evidence to rule out that null hypothesis.

If you want to check the table relating significance to Z-score yourself you can take a look at this link:
http://www.z-table.com/.